# Laravel Eloquent query builder for getting all rows in relationship third table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have the following migrations files:-

1- users :-

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('password');
```

2- books :-

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('hash')->unique();
    $table->text('book_name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

3- book_reads :-

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
    $table->foreign('book_id')->references('id')->on('books')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('selected_part');
    $table->string('reader_name')->nullable();
```

4- read_messages:-

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->longText('message');
    $table->boolean('is_readed')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('read_id');
    $table->foreign('read_id')->references('id')->on('book_reads')->onDelete('cascade');
```

- Model files:-

1- User Model:-

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book');    
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->books()->reads()->message();
        });
    });
}
```

2- Book Model :-

```
public function reads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BookRead');
}
```

3- BookRead Model:-

```
public function message()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ReadMessage','read_id');
}
```

In User Model file as you can see i am trying to create a query in messages() method to get all the messages belongs to that user Books . but the query i made gave error because i made it on wrong way.

How can i get all the user messages ?

Comment: Whats about in controller with this : `$user->books()-reads()->with('message')->get();` ???

Comment: @TalhaF. your way i think it will make two connections to DB, while i try to optimize the connection by one, also because i am using the messages in load method of User controller  $data = Auth::user()->load(['books' => function ($q){
            $q->where('status','!=','deleted');
        },'messages']);
        
        return response()->json($data);

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @TalhaF. no still